# How to compile a .ts file to .js in a Next.js project (to use it as a Web worker)?

Tags: typescript, next.js, web-worker, tsconfig

I have a TypeScript Next.js project:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

I want to add to it a Web worker. I know that the worker is started like `new Worker("worker.js")`.

What is the correct way to produce the `.js` file from `worker.ts`?

I could call `tsc` directly, but I am not sure that it is the right way, that I integrate it into `package.json` scripts correctly, and whether it uses `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need compile ts to js.
Just import the worker by

`const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.ts', import.meta.url));`

Here is example for you.

- Online Demo: https://nextjs-worker-example.vercel.app/
- Source Code: https://github.com/XDean/nextjs-worker-example

Comment: This solution is not compatible with Firebase FCM. The resulting service worker is not available in window.navigator.serviceWorker.ready